# How do I make a play again function?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on thie project for school and evrything needs to be in a function. Heres the code. Feel free the critic other stuff too, since im pretty knew to python!

```
def playAgain():
  pa = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
  while pa != "y" and pa != "n":
      if pa == "n":
          break
      elif pa == "y":
          continue
      else:
          print("That is not a valid answer.")
while true:
  Act1()
  gameOver()
```

I've tried putting the pa variable in the loop at the bottom, but that didnt work, even after I made pa global, so I really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What happens when you run `playAgain` (alone, without the rest of the code)? Does it behaves as expected? Hint: Try to add some print statements for the cases of `'y'` and `'n'`.

Comment: [Avoid globals](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you provide very little context of what you want to achieve with your function.

So I am making the following assumptions:

1. you have a main game loop, in which you want to iterate your game-logic:

```
while True:
   Act()
   if(playAgain()):
      continue
   else:
      break

gameOver()
```

See that I have moved the `gameOver()`-function out of your loop. So now every time your game-logic comes to an end playAgain() is lastly called - so all we have to do there is to return true or false, depending on if we want to continue playing.

2. So let's fix your `playAgain()`-function:

```
def playAgain():
  while True:
      pa = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
      if pa == "n":
          return False
      elif pa == "y":
          return True
      else:
          print("That is not a valid answer. Please enter 'y' or 'n'.")
```

Comment: Thanks, for spotting that! Corrected the typos

Answer (score 0):

I always try to make user input data consistent first, after that check go with your conditional statement and business logic.

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Do you want to play again?(y/n):").strip().lower()
    if user_input == 'n':
        break
    elif user_input == 'y':
        #Place your logic here.
        pass
    else:
        print("That is not a valid answer.")
```

Comment: The OP's idea of declaring a function to handle the problem of asking for input doesn't seem bad. While your logic would work, it breaks the functional approach. Also, what do you mean by _business logic_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop that prompts the user whether they want to play again and then, based on their input, either continues the game or ends it.

```
def playAgain():
  while True:
    pa = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
    if pa == "n":
        return False  # Exit the game
    elif pa == "y":
        return True  # Restart the game
    else:
         print("That is not a valid answer.")

def main():
   while True:
     Act1()
     gameOver()
     if not playAgain():
        break
```

I hope this helps to clarify your question!